# Mysql connect error : Unknown MySQL server host and Mysql connect error no 2005

Tags: php, time, indexing

when I connect via `mysql drive`

`mysqli_connect('localhost:9306')`- successfully returns Resource `id #21`

but when I use `'MySQLi' driver` it returns following error message:

```
 Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:9306' (3) and Mysqli Error No as 2005
```

Comment: yes,  i changed it to 'localhost' but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your host name is localhot not localhostt

As it showing error:

```
Unknown MySQL server host localhostt:9306
                            ^^^^ here
```

It should be `localhost`. check your code and change it to `localhost` instead of `localhostt`.